# how to compile code using glTexImage3D with emscripten

Tags: c++, opengl-es, sdl, emscripten

Tried to use glTexImage3D with emscripten, it complained with

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'glTexImage3D'; did you mean 'glTexImage3DOES'?
```

I thus tried to use glTexImage3DOES instead. The full line is:

```
glTexImage3DOES(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_ALPHA, shape2, shape1, shape0, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_FLOAT,&tex_data[0]);
```

However, then I get the error

```
error: undefined symbol: glTexImage3DOES (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: _glTexImage3DOES may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
```

Which I have no idea where to even start on how to solve. Do I really need to add to exported functions, and if so how would I do it? Or is this some other issue, which I suspect?

The headers I use are

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengles2.h>
```

compiling with emcc with flags

```
-std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s USE_SDL=2 -s MAX_WEBGL_VERSION=2  -O1
```

Comment: Did you try emulating opengl es? (`FULL_ES2` or `FULL_ES3` instead of `USE_WEBGL2`)

Comment: tried it, does not help

Comment: In OpenGL ES 3 (WebGL 2), [`glTexImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml) is in Core. `glTexImage3DOES` is the name of the function in the OpenGL ES 2.0 extension [`OES_texture_3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_texture_3D.txt). Also, don't use `SDL_opengles2.h`, but use `GLES3/gl3.h` instead (since WebGL2 ~= OpenGL ES 3).

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but it worked when I added `-s USE_WEBGL=1` which presumably adds the linkable libs into the mix. I think you may find your problem is fixed if you use `GLES3/gl3.h` ?